# Mobile menu cloe after transition end

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom, react-hooks

I have a problem with React. I would like my mobile menu to close only after the end of the transition on my last span of the Hover-Clone div.

I managed to do something but every second I reopen the menu it closes automatically.

I don't understand how I can make it work?
Should I use useTransition, useRef, useHook?

[Header.jsx](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pCQle.jpg)

```
const [isActive, setIsActive] = useState(false);

  const showNavBar = () => {
    setIsActive(!isActive);
  };

  const spanEnd = document.querySelectorAll('.end');

  spanEnd.forEach(l => {
    if (isActive === true) {
      l.addEventListener('transitionend', () => {
        showNavBar();
      });
    }
  }); 

 <nav className={isActive ? Style.navBarMobile : Style.navBar}>
    <ul className={Style.navBarList}>
      <li className={Style.navBarListItem}>
        <NavLink className={Style.navBarListLink} to='/a_propos'>
          <div className={Style.original}>
            <span>à</span>
            <span>&nbsp;</span>
            <span>p</span>
            <span>r</span>
            <span>o</span>
            <span>p</span>
            <span>o</span>
            <span>s</span>
          </div>
          <div className={Style.hoverClone}>
            <span>à</span>
            <span>&nbsp;</span>
            <span>p</span>
            <span>r</span>
            <span>o</span>
            <span>p</span>
            <span>o</span>
            <span className='end'>s</span>
          </div>
        </NavLink>
      </li>
```

Kind Regards

Comment: If you want an answer, you should probably isolate snippets of code rather than a picture that is huge and no one will read

Also you should describe how you need it to behave, and how you try to do it currently, rather than how it behave currently

Answer (score 0):

*Disclaimer: I'm not a react beast*

Your `showNavBar` method isn't actually showing the navbar, but rather toggling it. If it's closed, it will open it, if opened, it will close it.

- If you want that, you should probably rename your method for clarity (`toggleNavBar`)
- If you want it to really do what is says (which is my guess), you
  should update the content with `setIsActive(true)` instead

Give the second option a try and see what happens

*edit*
As a matter of fact you probably still need the toggle option for the open/close button

So you could do

```js
const ToggleNavBar = (to = null) => {
    const end_state = to === null ? !isActive : to
    
    setIsActive(end_state);
  };
```

then use it for your button like

```js
// ...
onClick={() => toggleNavBar()}
// ...
```

And for your span loop

```js
//...
toggleNavBar(true)
//...
```

Comment: it does not work :/

Comment: what is the issue?

Comment: I just tried what you suggested. I have just tried what you suggested. In fact, the menu opens well but once the menu is open it doesn't want to close anymore.

Comment: If you put some logger in the toggleNavBar what does it says when you try to close it ?

Comment: It returns the function complete ' const end_state = to === null ?isActive : to;

    setIsActive(end_state);'

Comment: I mean, if you add a `console.log("to: ", to, "isActive: ", isActive, "end state: ", end_state)` bellow the variable assignation

Comment: It returns that : µƒ () {
    let to = arguments.length > 0 && arguments[0] !== undefined ? arguments[0] : null;
    const end_state = to === null ? !isActive : to;
    setIsActive(end_state);
    console.log('to: ', to,…

Comment: I don't understand your response ...
I'm not sure my debug line of code is 100% perfect but my question is :

if you log or put a debug in your method, just between after set end_state and BEFORE set isActive, what are the values of those 3 variables when you try to close the side bar (to, isActive, and end_state)

Comment: maybe you can open a https://codesandbox.io/ with your example it will be easier to debug

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/kind-knuth-xdptp2?file=/src/NavBar.jsx&resolutionWidth=320&resolutionHeight=675

Comment: I copied and pasted but I don't have the same behaviour on sandbox as on my local.

Comment: `onClick={() => toggleNavBar()}` instead of `onClick=toggleNavBar` did the trick

https://codesandbox.io/s/fragrant-silence-c1rqb0?file=/src/NavBar.jsx:3248-3278

Though now your sidebar close when you stay hover a many item because at the end of your neat animation, it triggers a `spanEnd`

Comment: Thanks for the help, I'm almost there, but how can I make it so that it doesn't go off once a click?

Comment: Not sure to understand
How the above sandbox isn't working as expected. What is the behaviour you need to change

Comment: I can't reproduce the same thing on my localHost when I copy and paste the code from sandBox

Comment: Sorry I can't help you further then

But from the code you gave above and what we have in the code sandbox, it's partially the solution
Your localhost code probably contains things that has other side effects